# How to convert only one select-option box to button-group not all?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having troubles with converting certain select-option box to button-group. I'm using [this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Bootstrap-Plugin-To-Convert-Select-Boxes-Into-Button-Groups-select-togglebutton-js.html) script for converting. It works great but it converts all my select options on the site (I have more than one on page). I need to add some class or id to function but not sure how.

I need this script to work only with specific select-options (with expl. class or id 'my-options')

```js
    <script>
    (function($) {
    // Define the togglebutton plugin.
    $.fn.togglebutton = function(opts) {
        // Apply the users options if exists.
        var settings = $.extend( {}, $.fn.togglebutton.defaults, opts);

        // For each select element.
        this.each(function() {
            var self = $(this);
            var multiple = this.multiple;

            // Retrieve all options.
            var options = self.children('option');
            // Create an array of buttons with the value of select options.
            var buttons = options.map(function(index, opt) {
                var button = $("<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'></button>")
                .prop('value', opt.value)
                .text(opt.text);

                // Add an `active` class if the option has been selected.
                if (opt.selected)
                    button.addClass("active");

                // Return the button.
                return button[0];
            });

            // For each button, implement the click button removing and adding
            // `active` class to simulate the toggle effect. And also change the
            // select selected option.
            buttons.each(function(index, btn) {
                $(btn).click(function() {
                    // Retrieve all buttons siblings of the clicked one with an
                    // `active` class !
                    var activeBtn = $(btn).siblings(".active");
                    var total = [];

                    // Remove all selected property on options.
                    self.children("option:selected").prop("selected", false);

                    // Check if the clicked button has the class `active`.
                    // Add or remove it according to the check.
                    if ($(btn).hasClass("active"))  {
                        $(btn).removeClass("active");
                    }
                    else {
                        $(btn).addClass("active");
                        options.val(btn.value).prop("selected", true);
                        total.push(btn.value);
                    }
                   
                    // If the select allow multiple values, remove all active
                    // class to the other buttons (to keep only the last clicked
                    // button).
                    if (!multiple) {
                        activeBtn.removeClass("active");
                    }

                    // Push all active buttons value in an array.
                    activeBtn.each(function(index, btn) {
                        total.push(btn.value);
                    });

                    // Change selected options of the select.
                    self.val(total).change();
                });
            });

            // Group all the buttons in a `div` element.
            var btnGroup = $("<div class='btn-group btn-group-toggle' data-toggle='buttons'>").append(buttons);
            // Include the buttons group after the select element.
            self.after(btnGroup);
            // Hide the display element.
            self.hide();
        });
    };

    // Set the defaults options of the plugin.
    $.fn.togglebutton.defaults = {
    };

    }(jQuery));
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('select').togglebutton();
        })
    </script>
```

```html
<div class="row" id="dropdownopen1">
 <div class="col-sm-12">
  <select class="form-control my-options" id="airporttransclick1" name="selected_option1">
   <option value="0">CITY to CITY / RURAL</option>
   <option value="1" id="gotoairport">LEAVING THE AIRPORT</option>
   <option value="2" id="leavetheairport">GOING TO THE AIRPORT</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

I hope you understand what I mean

Thank you very much
R

Comment: Can't you use the id in the selector rather than the tagName?

Comment: Im not really familiar with javascript so I'm not sure how to add this to the scipt itself? All the classes, id's and names already in the options html needs to be there because they open some other forms below when clicked.

Comment: Just change `$('select').togglebutton()` to `$('#airporttransclick1').togglebutton()` and it will only affect the one with that `id`

Comment: Yeees, thank you very much. It works perfect now. Only one word was needed, lol :P